# Spring data Derived Queries with Multiple Condition and one parameter

Tags: java, spring-data

How can I create a derived query methods in Spring data which select result based on multiple conditions but with only one parameter.

```
List<Entity> findById1OrId2OrId3(String id1OrId2OrId3);
```

Something like this example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible with derived queries.

Alternatively,

```
@Query("from Entity e where e.id1 = ?0 or e.id2 = ?0 or e.id3 = ?0")
List<Entity> findById1OrId2OrId3(String singleId);
```

Comment: It throws error : Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters

Comment: Can you try with `?1` instead of `?0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "In" and make list of Ids then make a new derived query to achieve this